# Creating Bookmark folder in browser

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet, bookmarks

I need to create a folder in bookmark of browser with some links to show. How can I achieve this with Javascript or any other way.

I tried in google but didn't found any help..Is it possible to create bookmark folder using javascript or other languages?

I know through bookmarklet I can drag and drop the link..But, I need a folder that contains set of links..Is it possible through bookmarklet?

Comment: This is not possible.

Comment: I think it's not (and should never be) implemented, for obvious security reasons.

Comment: similar question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30752526/bookmark-folder-creation-using-javascript